# "EROR: 0:1: ' ' : version '400" is not supported" Error Occurs OpenGL on Mac

Tags: java, macos, opengl, shader, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL 3 on MacOS Mojave and I can't compile a shader with #version 400 core I keep getting the error. ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '400' is not supported. What code do I have to add to get this version of GLSL to work.

I've tried to add,

```
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL30.GL_TRUE);
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

But it didn't seem to fix the problem.

This is my current shader class,

```
public class Shader {

    private int id;

    public Shader(String vertDir, String fragDir) {

        id = glCreateProgram();

        int vertex = loadShader("assets/shaders/" + vertDir, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        int fragment = loadShader("assets/shaders/" + fragDir, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        glAttachShader(id, vertex);
        glAttachShader(id, fragment);

        glLinkProgram(id);
        glValidateProgram(id);
    }

    public void enable() {
        GL20.glUseProgram(id);
    }

    public void disable() {
        GL20.glUseProgram(0);
    }

    private static int loadShader(String file, int type){
        StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                shaderSource.append(line).append("//\n");
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        int shaderID = glCreateShader(type);
        glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
        glCompileShader(shaderID);
        if(glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS )== GL11.GL_FALSE){
            System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 500));
            System.err.println("Could not compile shader!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return shaderID;
    }

}
```

Comment: So what OpenGL context version did you actualy get?

Comment: What's the version of your OpenGL context?  `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`.

Comment: Asking for 3.2 but using 4.0 features doesn't really fit together too well...

Comment: @Cubic: The highest version I could go to with the #version was #version 120.

Comment: @Nick227889 You need to create the context with the right version. You're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score -1):

There is simply *no way* to use `#version 400` on mac because the GPU drivers are tied to the MacOS version, and there is no way to update them. Also, apple has deprecated OpenGL so support for it sucks on mac.

Because GPU drivers are tied to the MacOS version, the OpenGL and GLSL versions are also tied to it, and there is no way to upgrade beyond `#version 120` or OpenGL 2.1

You either need to switch computers/OS or stick to GLSL `#version 120`

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. Apple/MacOS should be supporting up to OpenGL 4.1 ([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823)). Op requests a 3.2 context (which is the problem here), but should be able to get a 4.1 context.

Comment: This isn't true. Higher versions of OpenGL are supported on Mac, you just can't get backwards compatible contexts... I'm not even sure if 4.x even has backwards compatible versions though.